# Linker errors while migrating from x32 to x64

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have recently migrated a project from x32 to x64 in VS professional 2008 and I'm getting this weird linker errors:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_PostMessageW
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_FlushFileBuffers
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WriteFile
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_WaitForSingleObject
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetFilePointer
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_EnterCriticalSection
...
```

And more of this nature.
I am including **shlwapi.lib** in the linker.
Running on Windows 7 x64.

Additional Dependencies:

[image]

Comment: did you make sure to install the libraries when you installed the x64 compilers? You may also need to set the Linker to be Machine(x64).

Comment: If you can't get this working there is always [the windows 7.1 sdk](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) which has a utility to set itself as the build environment for VS2008.

Comment: Linker has Target machine X64

Comment: Problem is likely that your lib directory contains 32 bit .lib files. You'll need to update that in the x64 config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for my problem was setting **Linker > General > Additional Library Directories** with `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib\x64"` instead of `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib"`.

Comment: WOW! An answer that redirected me to the correct path path of adding `;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\x64"` to the field!

Comment: May be there is a less hardcoded way to do it than referring to an absolute path!

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the x64 configuration is selected.  Right-click your project in the Solution Explorer window, Properties, Linker, Input.  Click on the Additional Dependencies box and click the button that appears.

[image]

This is what it should look like if the project is configured correctly.  Note how the "Inherit" checkbox is ticked and how the inherited values list the standard SDK libraries.  Like kernel32.lib, the link library that has the definition for __imp_FlushFileBuffers, etc.  If it doesn't look like this in your project then you'll get these linker errors.

Comment: it seems to look like that, I have edited my question to include the window.